# How to get values from array I get from db?

Tags: php

I'm having issues getting 2 different row counts by using a conditional statement.

```
$sql = select sum(id = :id AND category = :cat) as count1, 
              sum(category = :cat) as count2 
       from furniture;
$stmt = $connectdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':cat'=>"1"));
$resulta = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rowCount1 = count(count1);
$rowCount2 = count(count2);
```

How do I get the count value of count1 or count2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->fetchall()` method returns an array of result rows so you would have to do

```
$rowCount1 = $resulta[0]['count1'];
$rowCount2 = $resulta[0]['count2'];
```

Alternatively when you know there will only be one result row use

```
$resulta = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowCount1 = $resulta['count1'];
$rowCount2 = $resulta['count2'];
```

Just as an adendum, I have no idea what that query is doing or even if it would work!

Comment: I like the second of these :) don't forget $rowCount2 mind ;)

Comment: `$rowCount2` yup fixed it. Copy/Paste... the devils concept

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll` because your result will only contain 1 record:

```
$resulta = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To access that record do:

```
$rowCount1 = $resulta['count1'];
$rowCount2 = $resulta['count2'];
```

Besides that you need quotes around your query, and you need a where clause for your query:

```
$sql = "select sum(id) as count1, sum(category) as count2 from furniture where id = :id AND category = :cat";
```

However I doubt if this results in the desired result.

Comment: This solution would, unless I'm mistaken, leave both `$rowCount1` and `$rowCount2` as 1, because both `$resulta['count1']` and `$resulta['count2']` will both be of length 1? So you can get rid of the use of `count()` here, I'd wager.

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. My original query was `"SELECT cutID FROM furniture WHERE cutID = :custID AND category = :cat";` I chnaged it to the above coz I needed to get two count values from it. In my above query I've omitted `WHERE cutID = :custID AND category = :cat` will that change the output?

Comment: @d0ug7a5 True removed the count.

Comment: @Bekki - the `WHERE` clause can be whatever you want, that shouldn't affect SQLs ability to return the sum values - it will look at `cutID` and `category`, just not return them :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this. By the way, props to you for SUMming in SQL and not doing a horrible loop after :)

```
$resulta = $resulta[0];

$rowCount1 = $resulta['count1'];
$rowCount2 = $resulta['count2'];
```